# A Genetic Algorithm That Uses Variables as the Population Instead of Binary Digits

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, computer-science, genetic-algorithm

So I am aware that the bog standard Genetic Algorithm uses a string/array of binary digits as the population and then creates a series of Chromosomes out of this. After running, the chromosome with the highest fitness is presumed to be the most optimal solution. My question is, can I use array references as a replacement for the binary string/array.

For example, I am trying to create an algorithm which can automate aircraft queueing for a single runway. There are two inputs, aircraft wishing to take-off and aircraft wanting to land. Without going into too much detail, when an aircraft flys it produces distorted air behind it ([Wake Turbulence](https://www.ivao.aero/training/documentation/books/SPP_ADC_Wake_separation.pdf)) which can be extremely dangerous to succeeding aircraft. The weight/size of the aircraft is directly proportional to the size of the Wake Turbulence it produces. To stop it endangering other aircraft there is a required waiting period, which depends on the size of the leading aircraft, between each aircraft. An example of this is shown below:

```
Succeeding Aircraft   Lead Aircraft   Wake Turbulence Gap (NM)
-------------------   -------------   --------------------------
        H                   H                    4
        M                   H                    5
        S                   H                    6
        L                   H                    7
        H                   M                    3
...
```

*Where H = Heavy, M = Medium, S = Small, L = Light, NM = Nautical Miles;*

This data will be kept in a separate array which can be called by the fitness function. What I am wondering is whether I can make an effective genetic algorithm that mainly utilises Crossover because I cannot see a way how I could use Mutation.

The population would look like:

```
input: N001,N002,N003,N004,N005,...,N###
```

*Either separated by "," as a string or in a 1D array.*

Each Gene (i.e. N001) would refer to a position in a 2D array where the Wake Turbulence Category (H,M,S,L) and its desired action (Take-Off or Landing) would be stored. (i.e dataArray[001][1] = Wake Turbulence Category)

To calculate the fitness I have come up with this:

```
input = "N001.N002.N003.N004.N005.N006. ... Nnnn";

String [] aircraft = input.split(".");
double totalWeight = 0;

for (i = 0; i <= aircraft.length; i++) {
   priority = Array[i+1][1];
   action1 = Array[i][2];
   action2 = Array[i+1][2];
   wakeTurb1 = Array[i][3];
   wkaeTurb2 = Array[i+1][3];

   if(priority == 1) {
      totalWeight = totalWeight + 2^i;
   }

   if(action1 == 0 && action2 == 0) {
      wakeTurbVal = tAftT[wakeTurb2][wakeTurb1]; }
   else if(action1 == 0 && action2 == 1) {
      wakeTurbVal = lAftT[wakeTurb2][wakeTurb1]; }
   else if(action1 == 1 && action2 == 1) {
      wakeTurbVal = lAftL[wakeTurb2][wakeTurb1]; }
   else if(action1 = 1 && action2 == 0) {
      wakeTurbVal = tAftL[wakeTurb2][wakeTurb1]; }

   totalWeight = totalWeight + wakeTurbVal;
}
```

*Where priority 1 is an emergency and needs to land quickly. tAftL (Take-Off after a Landing) = an array where accurate wake turbulence values are stored for specific scenarios (Scenarios: tAftT, tAftL, lAftL, laftT). The array Array is basically a database with values stored for each aircraft.*

After running through the input, the resultant fitness for each chromosome would be 1/totalWeight.

**How would I build a Genetic Algorithm on this population and fitness function?**

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is an interesting problem, however as it is the question falls out of the scope of stack-overflow as it is [too broad  and seemingly opinion based](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) *(there are 2 pending close votes on this question)*. If you could, for example, edit your question and enrich it with your coding attempt at solving this then it would be great.

Comment: Have a look at the MOEA Framework (www.moeaframework.org). It provides excellent optimization options and allows for variables other than binary for use in a GA. Your problem may also be better suited for a multi-objective approach.